# Slow MySQL left join query with a small-medium size database

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I've got two basic tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` INT(32) NOT NULL auto_increment UNIQUE,
    `profile_type` INT(3),
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_login` DATETIME DEFAULT 0,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`, `profile_type`)
);

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     6455 |
+----------+


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_dept` (
    `id` INT(32) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `date_created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `client_id` INT(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `client_id`)
);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     9729 |
+----------+
```

For this example in the users table, profile_type & 32 selects all users configured with a client profile.

I'm attempting to speed up the queries on the users database, when running full searches, and lists.  Currently, I'm trying to get just a list of client usernames, and the count(id) of how many departments are assigned to that user.

Here are the queries I've tried, and their process time:

```
SELECT users.username 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN client_dept ON users.id = client_dept.client_id 
WHERE users.profile_type & 32 
GROUP BY users.id;
```

6020 rows in set (9.85 sec)

```
SELECT users.username 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT client_id, id 
    FROM client_dept 
    GROUP BY client_id 
) AS dept ON users.id = dept.client_id;
```

6020 rows in set (2.27 sec)

```
SELECT user.username 
FROM ( 
    SELECT username, id 
    FROM users WHERE profile_type & 32 
) AS user 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT client_id, id 
    FROM client_dept 
    GROUP BY client_id ) AS dept ON user.id = dept.client_id;
```

6020 rows in set (2.21 sec)

I've looked at other resources, and people seem to think that subqueries slow down SQL, but in this case, they're speeding it up.  However, I only have <10k users, so it shouldn't be taking 'seconds' to process, especially when I can query the database standard and get the usual <0.01 sec response.

Is there something I'm blatantly doing wrong, or are there any better methods to optimize the queries?  The general pages this will be used on (and is being used on) does a LIMIT $X,20, with various searching done via HAVING, but it's the main query being slow that worries me.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `INDEX` for the `client_id` on the `client_dept` table?

Comment: Did you index `users.id and dept.client_id`? Even without indexing, it seems slow.

Comment: This is not an answer; it should be a comment

Comment: These incomplete schemas? The `client_dept` table only has 3 columns; `id`, `date_created`, and `client_id`. You are linking a table just for a separate `date_created` column?

Comment: This is incomplete pseudo code.  The other fields are not indexed, and not referenced any more than possibly a 'where' clause, however even using this pseudo code as an example, it's horribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is just strange.

It posible optimize it, but i can offer other query to get same result.

```
   select u.username,c.c 

    from 
     (select count(*) as c,client_id from client_dept  group by client_id) as c
    left join 
      users as u 
      on u.id=c.client_id;
```

For speedup you can increase this variable in my.conf

```
sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 64M
```

Aloso you have to check that index on users(id) exist - probalby it exists.